# My car stereo stopped playing any audio, but it seems to be functioning as normal otherwise

Tags: electrical, audio, hyundai, electronics, accent

The OEM car stereo unit on my 2015 Hyundai accent stopped playing audio.

I have gone through every single setting (like mute) and tried every single source (am, fm, USB, bluetooth) and nothing plays audio. My phone pairs and all the controls of the head unit work and it has power. I have even tried disconnecting an reconnecting power.

Does this just mean the audio amp unit inside is toast? Is it possible that there are two separate fuses for the radio unit, or can the possibility of a fuse be excluded since the radio clearly has power?

Answer (score 1):

You vehicle may be equipped with a secondary audio amplifier. First thing I'd do is see about a fuse which might be powering this separately from the main audio. If the fuse is blown, there might be something else going on there which caused it to blow.